# How to test that my ubuntu is alive on network?

Tags: networking, ping

My question is , how to check that my ubuntu desktop is alive  , if `ping` is **disabled** in firewall  .

What Methods help me to figure out the status of my Ubuntu ?

Comment: The Network Manager applet isn't working?

Comment: can't go wrong with nmap/zenmap.